# cancel prependTo after using it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move a div to a div on the left, and then returning it to the right div.

I've got it working at a point that I can display the selected div on the left-div.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">

</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="block">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".block").click(function() {
    if ($(this).height() < 100) {
        $(this).animate({height:"100px",width:"100px"},500);
        $(this).prependTo("#left");
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({height:"50px",width:"50px"},500);
    }
});
```

(also see the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MMTu7/)

I could use the prependTo- or appendTo-method to return the div to the right div again, but then the order would be wrong...

Is there some kind of history-method or something like that, so I can change the order back to before I clicked the div?

Comment: You want to return the div on the left to the right once you click on another div located on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MMTu7/1/

```
$('.block').each(function( i ){
    $(this).addClass('idx'+i);
});

$("#left, #right").on('click', '.block', function() {

    var myIdx = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    //alert(myIdx)
    if ($(this).height() < 100) {
        $(this).clone().prependTo('#left').animate({height:100, width:100},500);
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({height:50, width:50},500, function(){
            $("#right ."+myIdx).show();
            $(this).remove();           
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, this works totally as I wanted it, thanks a lot. I also understand what you did there (I've only recently started to fiddle with jquery), so that's another learning moment for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try using this.

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    if ($(this).height() < 100) {
        $(this).animate({height:'100px',width:'100px'},500);
        $(this).prependTo('#left');
    }
    else {
        $(this).prependTo('#left');
        $(this).animate({height:'50px',width:'50px'},500);
    }
});
```

your divs would be reordered.

http://jsfiddle.net/SanketS/MMTu7/2/